# Sitecore Forms: Ajax is working on some pages but not on others for same form

Tags: sitecore-forms, ajax

I've got multiple pages that all use the same single form. I added the form to same additional pages of a different template. On the original pages, the form works as its supposed to - it shows the success message or validation errors in place on the page where the form was. However on the new pages, it redirects to /formbuilder?fxb.FormItemId=905cade2-cfe8-42f8-af72-2d7317835248&fxb.HtmlPrefix=fxb.1cbac25c-d3ff-494a-b282-cd9d369f2ece (whether it is success or validation error).

I know this is not an error with the submit actions since it does this for basic validation errors too (like if you leave the form blank and submit). This is the SAME form item in Sitecore, there is only one form item, and IsAjax is checked. What could be making it behave differently on different pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes when you doesn't include the following scripts in your Layout file. Here are these scripts.

```
@Html.RenderFormStyles()
@Html.RenderFormScripts()
```

So the error is happening because you doesn't have those in your cshtml file. Try to add these and it will solve your issue.

Read the below article to know how to add.

https://mostlysitecore.wordpress.com/2018/08/29/a-better-guide-to-sitecore-9-forms/

Comment: Thank you! That's probably it

Comment: So unfortunately that's not it - my main layout already includes both of those lines

Comment: @EricaStockwell-Alpert Can you open the page using `view page source` and see if you find these lines?

Comment: Got it - the lines were in the wrong place, as per https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16594/sitecore-9-forms-redirecting-to-formbuilder-link-on-submit - they need to be at the end of the body and not the head

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with javascript files.

Every form has a field called `Script`. Compare the working form field value with the new form field value - most probably on new form `Scripts` field value comes from Standard Values, while on the old forms it contains some custom scripts (e.g. different jquery version).

Make sure that Standard Values contains valid set of javascript files required for the forms to work:

[image: sitecore forms scripts]

Comment: It's the same form. It's literally the same item. So there's no different scripts or any other fields